# Fancybox is not loading with gallery

Tags: fancybox, zooming, jqzoom

None of the following click event loads fancybox gallery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {        
    jQuery('.zoomPup').bind('click',function(){
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
});
```

or

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {    
    $(".fancybox").click(function() {
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is with zoomPup (jqzoom) showing on top of an image with `<a href class="fancybox">`, when clicking on the zoomPup, the fancybox with a gallery should open.

Please refer to the example showing on http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples, Gallery & Lightbox. I am not using elevatezoom, currently using jqzoom, but my client wants the effect showing for the Gallery and Lightbox on elevateweb.co.uk.

Comment: Can we see more of your code? I don't know whether the link you've supplied is an example site for the plugin, or your test development area, but either way we prefer for code to actually be in the question. This is so that if the link breaks, or the page is modified, the question still makes sense.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors in your browser console? Does the click event do anything if you simply get the handler to run a `console.log()`?